# setText work in portrait but no in landscape

Tags: android, xml

I encountered a problem and i didn't find anything like that on internet.

I have two different layout, one for Portrait and one for landscape mode.
When I set a text to a textView in my Xml file (Test 123 for exemple), it appears in portrait mode but doesn't in land mode.

This is very confusing because yesterday it was working well and today it is not working and i don't remember changing anything on those xml files.

Here are my xml files

Portrait xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:fontFamily="@font/caprina_font"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:text="@string/session_comparison"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1pt"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumbs_up"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="19dp"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_triangle"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/etat_de_forme_text"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="test 1 2 3"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/blue_all_rounded_shape"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

LandScape xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/caprina_font"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/session_comparison"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1pt"
                android:background="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumbs_up"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="19dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_triangle"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/etat_de_forme_text"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="test 1 2 3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_all_rounded_shape"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.RadarChart
                    android:id="@+id/chart"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT :
I can't post the code because this is too long, so here is a link to download it : https://ufile.io/5js30

Comment: can you show java file

Comment: post error log..

Comment: How are you using `savedInstanceState` before and after rotating the screen?

Comment: I have no error logs, and i edit the post witht the Kotlin file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove padding from top and bottom in `LandScape.xml` file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  <== change to wrap_content
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:gravity="center">

   ...

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etat_de_forme_text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        //android:paddingTop="10dp"       <== remove this
        //android:paddingBottom="10dp"    <== remove this
        android:text="test 1 2 3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_all_rounded_shape"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
  ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: oh ok, now i can see some of the text (which i set programmaticaly in code). But the TextView height doesn't resize automaticaly for the content

Comment: It is working now, thanks you ! I understood a lot about wrap_content and match_parent !

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" // <= Add this since you are using...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp" // <= ...using this.
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumbs_up"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_triangle"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etat_de_forme_text"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="test 1 2 3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_all_rounded_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.RadarChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```